# Proof By Induction: Summation of Polynomial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

Prove by induction (weak or strong) that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(k + 1)^2= \frac{n(n + 1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

My **base case** is:

$n = 1$, which is true.

In my **Inductive Step**, I assume that: $$S(n)=\frac{n(n + 1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ holds for an arbitrary value of $n$.

Proving it then holds for $n+1$:
$$ S(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$$
$$ \phantom{S(n+1)}=\frac{(n+1)((n+2)(2n+2+1)}{6}$$
$$ \phantom{S(n+1)}=\frac{(n+1)((n+2)(2n+3)}{6}$$
$$ \phantom{S(n+1)}=\frac{2n^3+9n^2+13n+6}{6}$$

but can't see how my definition of $S(n)$ can be substituted into this final equation?

**[EDIT]** This isn’t a duplicate because the original summation of $(k+1)^2$ is what I’m originally provided with. The apparent duplicate question also doesn’t have a correct *proof by induction* answer associated with it.

Comment: This should be a duplicate ! Note that the sum is equal to $$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$

Comment: You do not have $S(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$, which is NOT the induction hypothesis $S(n) = \cdots$.

Comment: you need to show that $$S(n+1)=S(n)+(n+1)^2$$

Comment: @JohnMa not sure what you’re talking about? I do indeed have that as my induction hypothesis?

Comment: $S(n+1)=\frac{(n+1)((n+1)+1)(2(n+1)+1)}{6}$ is what you need to prove, @adamcasey

Comment: @JohnMa that’s what I’m asking help for...

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**:
\begin{align}
S(n+1)&=S(n)+(n+1)^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6+(n+1)^2\\
&=\frac{n+1}6\bigl(n(2n+1)+6(n+1)\bigr)=\frac{(n+1)(2n^2+7n+6)}6.
\end{align}
Now observe that $n=-2$ is a root of the second factor, so it is divisible by $n+2$.